# Entity Framework: Server did not respond within the specified time out interval

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, devart

I am trying to access remote Oracle database using vpn connection. Using Oracle Sql Developer tool I am able to connect the database. But when I use ADO.NET model and Devart dotconnect for Oracle, it gives me error that server did not respond with in specified timeout interval.

[image]

Any one has face this issue?

**UPDATE:** I increases the timeout to 60s from default 15s. Now I am getting error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st Issue is quiet common that server did not respond in defined time, increasing the connection time should do the trick. For this just append 
;connection timeout = 60; (here time in seconds) to your connection string.

2nd After your update looks like Tns is not resolved properly:
You can check:

1. Do the tnsping (DB name in tns ora file). See you should not get any error and connection should be ok.
2. If problem still persist check your oracle home in registry have the correct path in case you have multiple client.